# NHibernate inserting wrong Id

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate

I am using MVC razor 5
I'm making managment page to add SelectList values (like Car models)

I have values in my car models table:

```
--------------------------------------
Id | Name | Deleted
1  | BMW  | False
2  | Audi | False
3  | Ford | False
4  | BMW5 | False
5  | SEAT | False
--------------------------------------
```

When i add new value id becomes 130++

I have noticed that my main class last records Id is 130.
And when I insert a record in car model class Id is the nextval(Id) of main class

But these two tables does not share same Controller or so...
All sessions are closed by transaction.Commit() so session closes.
What may be wrong?

Nhibernate class mapping:

```
  <class name="web_nt.Models.Class.CarModel" table="car_model" schema="public">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="model_name" />
    <property name="deleted" />
  </class>
```

Comment: eddited, maybe its generator class fault?

Comment: Generator was what I suspected! ;) but native is ok... well for SQL Sever world. Maybe in postgresql you can have turned on some shared sequence generators... but sorry, no experience with postgresql

Answer (score 0):

It was generator class fault.
To use postgres sequence I needed to specify it (NHibernate does not always catch it itself)

```
  <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">car_model_id_sequence</param>
  </generator>
```